# Unable to install node.js v8 on CentOS 7

Tags: node.js, linux, centos7

I tried following the instructions on [nodesource](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-8-tutorial-linux-via-package-manager/) by running these commands as root:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
```

But when I run `node -v` afterward I can see that it only installed 0.10.48. I can see in the output of the second command that it's selecting the wrong version of the package for download:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * remi: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
2418 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:0.10.48-3.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=========================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Arch                                       Version                                            Repository                                Size
=========================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 nodejs                                     x86_64                                     0.10.48-3.el6                                      epel                                     2.1 M

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 2.1 M
Installed size: 7.1 M
Downloading Packages:
nodejs-0.10.48-3.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 MB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : nodejs-0.10.48-3.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                           1/1 
  Verifying  : nodejs-0.10.48-3.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                           1/1 

Installed:
  nodejs.x86_64 0:0.10.48-3.el6                                                                                                                                                          

Complete!
```

I've tried uninstalling with `yum remove -y nodejs npm` and then running `rm -fv /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource*`, `yum clean all`, `yum update` and then reinstalling but nothing seems to work.

Why doesn't it resolve to the v8 package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago and I was not able to install Node version 8 via the *nodesource* repository.
In fact, there is no `setup_8.x` script in the rpm repository yet.
I end up with [n](https://github.com/tj/n) package to get Node version 8:

```
# yum install nodejs  // you need to have npm installed
# npm install -g n
# n stable
# node -v  // v8.4.0
```

Comment: ahh interesting. so `yum install nodejs` installed an older version of node, and then you used `n` to install a newer version of node from the npm repo?

Comment: Absolutely. I used to prefer install Nodejs with yum repo but couldn't find any solution to get Node version 8 this way.